# How to easily maintain the latest versions of Apache/ MySQL/ PHP on CentOS 6.2?

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, software-updates

We have a few servers running CentOS 6.2 deploying web applications using Apache/ MySQL/ PHP.

In the past we've just regularly run "yum update" to keep all the software up to date.

As of right now the installed versions are:

- Apache 2.2.15
- MySQL 5.1.61
- PHP 5.3.3

When the latest released versions are:

- Apache 2.4.1
- MySQL 5.5.21
- PHP 5.3.10

We're web developers with a bit of Linux knowledge rather than server administrators so we want to be able keep everything patched to the latest (or near) version without having to go into the depths of compiling software or too much command line jiggery-pokery.

What is the best way for us to easily maintain the latest versions (or at least late as possible versions) on CentOS 6.2?

Comment: If you want the latest versions, don't run CentOS. CentOS is very conservative. Run something like Ubuntu (new release every 6 months).

Comment: Apache Httpd 2.4.1 was released on Monday last or thereabouts. I don't think you need to be in a particular rush to deploy it, since security updates for httpd will be continuing for quite a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm digging through old questions but hopefully this will still be of some use to you.

So if you want the absolute most up to date releases of those, your best bet is to get them directly from the projects themselves and build from sources.

If you are looking just looking to regularly make sure everything is up to date you might want to set a cron job that runs `yum update` nightly.  The guide that I keep in my bookmarks for when I'm having brain fart moments [is this one here](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html).  It should help you out in setting that up.

Lastly if you are looking to pull through yum the most recent packages possible, the fasttrack repo from CentOS might be your best bet.  Do a ctrl-f fasttrack on this [wiki page](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) for the info on it.  Although be forewarned I've never used that repo before and can't really say 100% that it's what you will need or that it won't break things.